# Looking for the name of an old cartoon about a princess traveling on a space train taken hostage by blue androids

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Back in the days I had a cartoon on VHS. The case said that it's not the only episode of this cartoon, but I've never got my hands on the other episodes.

Long story short - it all started in some (not so) distant future with a war on some Earth-like planet. A king orders his soldier to take the princess into space on a space train called 'Messenger-seven'. Then they get ambushed by some blue-skinned androids and are held hostage in their base located on some asteroid. In the end they manage to escape and flood the base so all androids end up short-circuiting.

The art was anime-like, but I can't be sure now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I did a bit more googling, tweaking the search query in different ways and finally found it - the cartoon is called 'Protectors of Universe'. And 'Messenger 7' turned out to be a crappy dubbing of 'Mazinger 7'.